# Cannot prompt wallet to connect

Tags: polkadot-js

I have been having series of errors and I have not been able to find a solution online. Please can anyone help me? I want to prompt users to connect wallet i.e when the connect button is clicked talisman, polkadotjs etc should pop up for confirmation.

This is the function:

```js
async function handleConnect () {
  const provider = new WsProvider(WS_SECOND_ENDPOINT);
  const oneApi = await ApiPromise.create({ provider });
  const [chain, nodeName, nodeVersion] = await Promise.all([
    oneApi.rpc.system.chain(),
    oneApi.rpc.system.name(),
    oneApi.rpc.system.version()
  ]);
await oneApi.connect();
  console.log(`You are connected to chain ${chain} using ${nodeName} v${nodeVersion}`);
}
```

[image]
[image]

When i remove `await oneApi.connect();` I get the error below on the console:

```
caught (in promise) Error: WebSocket is already connected
    at WsProvider.connect (index.js:314:19)
    at RpcCore.connect (bundle.js:91:30)
    at ApiPromise.connect (index.js:29:30)
    at newTest (App.tsx:49:14)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```js
import { ApiPromise, WsProvider } from "@polkadot/api";

export const connect = async () => {
    const provider = new WsProvider("wss://karura.api.onfinality.io/public-ws");
    const oneApi = new ApiPromise({ provider });
    await oneApi.isReadyOrError;

    const [chain, nodeName, nodeVersion] = await Promise.all([
        oneApi.rpc.system.chain(),
        oneApi.rpc.system.name(),
        oneApi.rpc.system.version()
    ]);

    console.log(`You are connected to chain ${chain} using ${nodeName} v${nodeVersion}`);
    process.exit()
}
```

Output:

```
2023-04-23 09:54:28        REGISTRY: Unknown signed extensions SetEvmOrigin found, treating them as no-effect
2023-04-23 09:54:28        API/INIT: RPC methods not decorated: chainHead_unstable_body, chainHead_unstable_call, chainHead_unstable_follow, chainHead_unstable_genesisHash, chainHead_unstable_header, chainHead_unstable_stopBody, chainHead_unstable_stopCall, chainHead_unstable_stopStorage, chainHead_unstable_storage, chainHead_unstable_unfollow, chainHead_unstable_unpin, evm_blockLimits, evm_call, evm_estimateResources, oracle_getAllValues, oracle_getValue, tokens_queryExistentialDeposit, transaction_unstable_submitAndWatch, transaction_unstable_unwatch
You are connected to chain Karura using Acala Node v2.13.0-unknown
```

Also, you may want to look at this:

- https://polkadot.js.org/docs/extension/usage